# Having import, class confusion in basic java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program that imports a string file, parses it for proper words, and then filters out and prints unique words. I've set up one class to import the .txt file and put the words into an ArrayList:

```
public class RawText 
{
    ArrayList<String> allWords = new ArrayList<String>();  //raw list of words

/**
 * This method reads strings from file, filters for only upper/lowercase strings and adds to allWords
 * @throws IOException 
 * @params filename: a string filename
 */
public void add(String filename) throws IOException
{
    File inFile = new File(filename);         //inst. file import for raw
    Scanner read = new Scanner(inFile);         //inst. scanner object

    while (read.hasNext())                      //reads until end of text
    {
        String word = read.next();              //scanner reads next complete string
        word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z", ""); //filters out non-alphabet chars
        allWords.add(word);                     //adds 'stripped-down' string to list
    }
    read.close();
}
```

}

And the Main(), filtering method and print:

```
public class Source1 {
static ArrayList<String> allWords = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    RawText rt = new RawText();             //Inst. class for import
    Source1 source = new Source1();         //Inst. class variables
    rt.add("text.txt");                     //creates arraylist of raw words
    removeRepeats();                        //run method to filter out repeats

    printArray(source.allWords);            //prints unfiltered array
    printArray(source.uniqueWords);         //prints filtered array
}

/**
 * matches words against previously used words, and strips out repeats
 * @params words any string array to be filtered for repeat words
 */
public static void removeRepeats()
{
    boolean isUnique = false;           //default State for rejecting repeat words
    uniqueWords.add(0) = allWords.get(0);//Prime the matching algorithm at first word

    int i = 0;                          //i counts up each raw word to be tested
    while (i < allWords.size())
    {
        int j = 0;                      //j counts up each previous unique word
        while (j < uniqueWords.size())  //runs through all current uniques
        {
            isUnique = true;            //set state to true
            if (allWords.get(i) == uniqueWords.get(j))
                isUnique = false;       //if any words match, eval to false
            j++;
        }

        if (isUnique = true)            //Only if state remains true, add raw word to uniques
            uniqueWords.add(allWords.get(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

I need to know if there's a more appropriate/effective way to set up my classes, and if there would be a reason that uniquewords.add() doesn't work in the second line of the removeRepeats() method.

Thank you.

Comment: you want to know why adding an integer to a string ArrayList doesn't work?

Comment: uniqueWords.add(0) = allWords.get(0); what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to set the first word of the empty uniqueWords list to the same as the first word of allWords. That way when the loop runs there won't be an empty uniqueWords list.

Comment: replace `uniqueWords.add(0) = allWords.get(0);` with `uniqueWords.add(allWords.get(0));`

Comment: Replace if (allWords.get(i) == uniqueWords.get(j))
             with if ( allWords.get(i).equals(uniqueWords.get(j)) and other thing - Don't you break the while loop if isUnique== false?

Comment: Also having an exception thrown when i instantiate the RawText object:    RawText rt = new RawText();

Comment: @fluffywarthog, What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: @BoDidely it's "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: Program1.RawText at Program1.Source1.main(Source1.java:24)"

Comment: @BoDidely fixed: had the wrong package imported, causing the exception. now I have a "unreported exception; IOException must be caught or declared" when I pass "text.txt" to rt.add() in Main().

Comment: @fluffywarthog, Your method add() in RawText throws IOException. That means that you need to handle this exception when you call the method. In your main, you'll want to enclose the method call in a try{} block followed by a catch(IOException e) {}. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your problems:

```
uniqueWords.add(0) = allWords.get(0);
```

Here, you are adding an integer, 0, to your ArrayList of Strings. You probably want:

```
uniqueWords.add(allWords.get(0));
```

Also, later on you're comparing Strings with == :

```
if (allWords.get(i) == uniqueWords.get(j))
```

== should only be used when comparing primitive data types. To compare Strings, use the method equals(String) or equalsIgnoreCase(String):

```
if (allWords.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(uniqueWords.get(j))
```